# C++ lambda function capture anomaly?

Tags: c++, lambda, capture

I have this following code:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "LOL";
    auto f = [s](string s) // [=](string s) //****
    { cout << s << endl; };
    f("WTF");
}
```

My question is about the line marked with //****.

In the first case (with [s]) the output is "LOL".

In the second case (with [=]) the output is "WTF".

I don't understand why.

I thought that [=] tells the lambda to capture all the scope's variables.
Why is there a difference in the behavior?

Comment: Don't keep reusing the same variable name. That will probably make the issue clearer. This seems almost certainly like a scoping issue.

Comment: The parameter shadows any captured variables.

Comment: Any reason your naming the lambda parameter and the capture the same?  Makes knowing what is going on harder when you do.

Comment: The same variable's name it in order to understand the mechanism behind it (had similar question in exam).

Comment: @KobiT, You should update your question. It currently sounds like you want to know why the output is different, not fine details of captures.

Comment: It's the same. I wanna know why there's a different output in between [s] and [=] in this specific case.

Comment: @user0042 Why doesn't it shadow when using [=]?

Comment: I can't reproduce your described behavior. With VS 2017, it prints "WTF" in both cases.

Comment: @MooseBoys that's weird. Maybe some end case that is undefined in the language?

Comment: @user0042 my question is not duplication of the linked one.
Mine is about the difference between [vars] and [=] as exampled in the attached code.

Comment: _@KobiT_ Ask @Praetorian, I voted to close for other reasons.

Comment: @user0042 what reasons? If I may ask

Comment: Last time I've checked the case `[s](string s)` [was considered ill-formed](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-5) (this would actually make sense).

Comment: @KobiT As explained in the duplicate and the link in the comment above, `[s](std::string s){...}` is ill-formed, so there's no point in speculating about the difference between `[s]` and `[=]` in your example.